# security.xml strange error using Spring 

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to configure [Spring Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Security) in my simple application. Here is my configuration file, `security.xml`:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <http>
        <form-login login-page="/login/" authentication-failure-url="/fail/" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService' />
    </authentication-manager>

    <b:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="my.package.security.MyUserDataService" />
</beans:beans>
```

I got following errors with deploying:

> The prefix "beans" for element "beans:beans" is not bound.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing up the `beans` and `b` prefixes.  You've declared the `b` prefix, and then used the `beans` one. You need to pick one and stick with it.  For example, replace

```
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

with

```
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

and then

```
<b:bean...
```

with

```
<beans:bean...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the namespace as `b:` and using it everywhere except the enclosing `beans` tag, in which you're using `beans:beans` instead of `b:beans`.